# fetching cursor records in to a array throwing error

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-cursor

When I execute the function below, I am getting the error:

```
date/time field value out of range: "0"
```

Could you please help me figure out what is wrong with this code.

This is thrown at `FETCH c_dt_coursor INTO v_idetail;`

```
create schema if not exists stbschema;

create type stbschema.itdtls as (
   ID NUMERIC,
   TD NUMERIC,
   SDT TIMESTAMP(0),
   RUP NUMERIC,
   EDT TIMESTAMP(0)
);

do $$
begin
CREATE DOMAIN stbschema.itdtls_v as stbschema.itdtls[];
EXCEPTION
    WHEN duplicate_object THEN null;
END $$;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stbschema.f1(p_ant numeric, p_dt timestamp without time zone, p_id numeric, p_dtf timestamp without time zone, p_tf character varying, OUT p_amount numeric, OUT p_sts boolean)
 RETURNS record
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
v_sts            BOOLEAN := FALSE;
v_idetail stbschema.itdtls_v;

   c_dt_coursor cursor is 
   select array(select row(id,
          mny,
          sdt, 
          rat, 
          coalesce(edt, p_dt))
     from idtls  
    where id = p_id 
      and sdt <= p_dt 
      and coalesce(edt, p_dt) > p_dtf  
     order by sdt,mny);

  begin

    p_amount := 0;
    OPEN c_dt_coursor;
    FETCH c_dt_coursor INTO v_idetail;
    CLOSE c_dt_coursor;

    v_sts := TRUE;
    p_sts := v_sts;
    return;
  end $function$;
```

An example row returned from the cursor is

```
{"(1,10,\"2001-01-01 00:00:00\",500,\"2009-01-01 12:00:00\")"}
```

Comment: These are values being passed to the function.p_ant 200
p_dt 2005-01-01 12:00:00
p_id 1
p_dtf 2003-01-01 00:00:00
p_tf F
p_amount NULL
p_sts NULL

Comment: I don't see any reason to use a cursor here.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `CREATE TYPE` (or `CREATE TABLE`) statement for `itdtls`

Answer (score 0):

Table `stbschema.itdtls` has a column of a date/time type, but the query in the cursor definition returns 0 for some field of the value where that is not possible.

An example would be

```
2019-00-01
```

So when PostgreSQL tries to cast the array to an array of `stbschema.itdtls`, it has to report an error.

Perhaps you can add a `CASE` expression to the query that replaces such values with a valid value.

Comment: The one row that you have shown will not cause the error. There must be different data in the table.

Comment: {"(1,10,\"2001-01-01 00:00:00\",500,\"2009-01-01 12:00:00\")","(1,0,\"2006-01-01 00:00:00\",500,\"2009-01-01 12:00:00\")","(1,101,\"2006-01-01 00:00:00\",700,\"2009-01-01 12:00:00\")"}

I think the problem with the second field value.For first record (1,10,\"2001-01-01 00:00:00\",500,\"2009-01-01 12:00:00\") no error
For second record (1,0,\"2006-01-01 00:00:00\",500,\"2009-01-01 12:00:00\") getting error as date/time field value out of range: "0"
For third record (1,101,\"2006-01-01 00:00:00\",700,\"2009-01-01 12:00:00\") getting error as invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "101"

Comment: I think second field value is taking as third field.It's not mapping properly.
Could you please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please help me.

Comment: I cannot debug this for you. I don't know the definition of `idtls`. I don't have the time to locally build a copy of your database, and there is nothing obviously wrong. I'd build a lot of `RAISE NOTICE` into the function and check what is returned from the cursor *before* it is cast to `v_idetail`. Oh, wait a minute: That variable is of an array type, and you are trying to assign a record to it? How is that supposed to work?